# How to inject constants in config step in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to inject constants into the `app.config()` step in angularjs. But is does not work. How could I achieve this?

```
var app = angular.module(..);

app.constant('MY_CONST', {
    //...
};

app.config(['MY_CONST', function($routeProvider, MY_CONST) {
    //...
}
```

Result: `Error [$injector:modulerr]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to inject `$routeProvider` in config.

```
app.constant('MY_CONST', {
    //...
}); // Missing ) here

app.config(['$routeProvider', 'MY_CONST', function($routeProvider, MY_CONST) {
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //...
}); // Missing ) here
```